# Добавить в корзину при помощи ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Есть функция, которая добавляет товар в корзину:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".add-to-cart").click(function () {
                var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
                var size = $(".radio").attr("data-id");
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {product: id, count: $('.count-value').val(), size: size}
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Так же есть кнопки, которые показывают размер товара:

```
 <div class="size">
    <?
       $minSize = substr($product['size'], 0, 2);
       $maxSize = substr($product['size'], 3, 4);
         for ($i=$minSize;$i<=$maxSize;$i++) {
           echo "<input class='radio' data-id='$i' type=\"radio\" value='$i' name=\"option\" id=\"radio$i\" />";
           echo "<label class='label-radio' data-id='$i' for=\"radio$i\">$i</label>";
         }
     ?>
  </div>
```

Функция которая добавляет товар в БД не различает какой размер был указан т.е какая кнопка была нажата перед тем как добавить. Вот серверная часть:

```
if (isset($_POST['product'])) {
            $productId = $_POST['product'];
            $count = $_POST['count'];
            $size = $_POST['size'];
            $color = $_POST['color'];
            $result = Carting::addToCart($productId,$count,$userId,$size);
        }
```

Comment: Задайте сам вопрос

Comment: Читайте по внимательнее: Функция которая добавляет товар в БД не различает какой размер был указан т.е какая кнопка была нажата перед тем как добавить

Comment: @AziretKadykeev во-первых, вопрос заканчивается на знак "?")) а во-вторых, у вас input'ы называются `option`, а проверяете вы `size`

Comment: @DaemonHK у этих `option` есть класс `.radio` значение которых хранятся в переменной `size`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо за помощь вот решение к которому я пришел:

```
  var size = $('input[name=option]:checked').val();
```